# Is there any way to cold reboot via software?

Tags: linux, system-shutdown

1. An embedded Linux device may suddenly shut down during operation. When powered on again, the kernel records the restart type as cold_boot. At the same time, there is no abnormal information in the kernel log at the shutdown moment, which is similar to the system power failure.
2. I want to know whether the software can cause the system cold_boot or only the hardware. If the software can cause the system to suddenly power off and shut down, what software bug may be the cause and how to locate the cause.

```
# cat /proc/cmdline
init=/init console=ttyS0,115200 no_console_suspend earlycon=aml-uart,0xff803000 ramoops.pstore_en=1 ramoops.record_size=0x8000 ramoops.console_size=0x4000 phy_idx= hdr_policy=0 hdr_priority= otg_device=1 
reboot_mode_android=normal logo=osd0,loaded,0x3d800000 fb_width=1920 fb_height=1080 display_bpp=16 outputmode=576cvbs vout=576cvbs,enable panel_type=lcd_1 lcd_ctrl=0x00000083 hdmitx=,444,8bit hdmimode=1080p60hz 
hdmichecksum=0x00000000 dolby_vision_on=0 frac_rate_policy=1 hdmi_read_edid=1 cvbsmode=576cvbs osd_reverse=0 video_reverse=0 irq_check_en=0 androidboot.selinux=enforcing androidboot.firstboot=1 jtag=disable 
androidboot.hardware=amlogic androidboot.bootloader=U-Boot 2015.01 androidboot.build.expect.baseband=N/A androidboot.serialno=1234567890 androidboot.wificountrycode=US androidboot.oem.key1=ATV00104319 rootfstype=ramfs androidboot.rpmb_state=0 
reboot_mode=cold_boot
```

Comment: Where do you get this record? (Exact cmds please).

Comment: linux kernel log record,  you can also confirm reboot type by  cat /proc/cmdline

Comment: What device and how is it running Linux? RTOS? Much will depend on whether it is more a full computer with all the wonderful virtual-memory and address protections like an Intel NUC or whether it is a bare device like a TI MSP or Raspberry Pi Pico or Arduion that lack much of the formal memory boundary protections, but can still run a Linux kernel.

Comment: just like Raspberry Pi Pico or Arduion, it is a simple device .  I run Linux kernel 4.9.113 and some software on it, not RTOS

Comment: What exactly this device is? What part of software produces *reboot_mode=cold_boot* line? Look at its source and check which register indicates cold_boot. Read MCU datasheet, which conditions determine this reboot mode. If device has external hardware reset circuit controlled e.g. by GPIO, reboot may be triggered by software. It may be caused by power glitch. There are too many variants to speculate.

Comment: We are asking precise questions and getting back imprecise answers. Makes it hard to help you.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, gave me a lot of analytical ideas; At present, there is no possibility of software triggering shutdown. We are measuring the voltage around the SOC chip and checking the hardware cause